# MySQL One to Many and Many to Many Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: Hospitals, Inspections, and Violations. I need to formulate a query that returns all lighting violations with the inspection date, inspectors notes, and hospital name in one row per inspection.

A Hospital can have zero or more inspections. Inspections can have zero or more violations.

This is the query so far:

```
SELECT h.hospital_name AS Name, i.date AS Date, CONCAT_WS(', ', v.notes) AS Notes
FROM hospital_table h
LEFT JOIN inspection_table i ON h.id = i.hospital_id
INNER JOIN violation_table v ON i.id = v.inspection_id
WHERE v.type = 'Lighting'
ORDER BY i.date DESC;
```

There are instances where an inspection will have zero or more lighting violations. Essentially I need the result to look like:

```
| Name              | Date         | Notes                           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Burnaby General   | 18-09-2107   | Bath light..., bed sconce...    |
```

The result is close but in some cases, the dates are not correct. Can someone suggest a way to achieve what is required?

Comment: add more details + sample data + expected o/p

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) instead of `CONCAT_WS` to get all notes per hospital in one row.

```
SELECT h.hospital_name AS `name`, 
i.date AS `date`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(v.notes) AS Notes
FROM hospital_table h
LEFT JOIN inspection_table i ON h.id = i.hospital_id
LEFT JOIN violation_table v ON i.id = v.inspection_id
WHERE v.type = 'Lighting'
GROUP BY h.hospital_name
ORDER BY i.date DESC;
```

> Note: The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet.

For date i assume there will be multiple inspections per hospital to get the recent inspection date you can use `MAX(i.date)` and change `ORDER BY MAX(i.date)` or to get all inspection dates you can apply `GROUP_CONCAT` on i.date too